# How to prevent local storage overwriting values using JS

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have 4 buttons in HTML. In JS, I added an event listener to them (through a loop) so that everytime a button is clicked, I get the value and the name of the button. I put the value and name in an object and send the object to the local sotrage. The problem is that each time a button is clicked, the new values in the local stroage overwrite the previous entered ones. What should I do to keep all the values sent to the local store after a button is clicked? I´ve been reading and testing different options but nothing works.

My HTML

```
<div>
  <button class="add-cart" type="button" name="peperonni" value=".25">
    Add to cart
  </button>
  <button class="add-cart" type="button" name="meatballs" value=".35">
    Add to cart
  </button>
  <button class="add-cart" type="button" name="mushrooms" value=".40">
    Add to cart
  </button>
  <button class="add-cart" type="button" name="peperonni" value=".20">
    Add to cart
  </button>
</div>
```

My JS

`let addCart = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');`

```
 addCart[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
   let name = addCart[i].name;
   let price = addCart[i].value;
   const menuItem = {
     name: name,
     price: price,
   };
   window.localStorage.setItem('ProductsInCart', JSON.stringify(menuItem));
 });
}
```

Comment: Define `ProductsInCart` as an array of objects instead of a single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
addCart[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
 // get items from localStorage, or declare new one if not exist
 let menuItems = localStorage.getItem("ProductsInCart") || '[]';
 menuItems = JSON.parse(menuItems); 
 // declare and add the new item
 menuItems.push({ name: addCart[i].name, price: addCart[i].value });
 localStorage.setItem("ProductsInCart", JSON.stringify(menuItems));
});
```

Comment: Might as well skip the whole `menuItem` variable then.

Answer (score 2):

To update local storage without *replacing* it, you need to do it in a few steps:

1. Get the `ProductsInCart` entry from storage.
   (if it doesn't exist, create an empty array)
2. Add the new cart item to your array.
3. Save this new / updated array back into the `ProductsInCart` entry in your local storage.

So, simply put:

Read -> Update -> Write

Answer (score 1):

Push the new menu Item in the Menu Item Array

```
addCart[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
 let menuItems = window.localStorage.getItem("ProductsInCart");
 if (menuItems) {
   menuItems = JSON.parse(menuItems);
 } else {
   menuItems = [];
 }
 let name = addCart[i].name;
 let price = addCart[i].value;
 const menuItem = {
   name: name,
   price: price,
 };
 menuItems.push(menuItem);
 window.localStorage.setItem("ProductsInCart", JSON.stringify(menuItems));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The entry is being overwritten because you are always using the same key to store the data. Please change the key every time to prevent overwriting the previous entry.

```js
window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(menuItem));
```

You can try:

```js
let addCart = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart'); 

 addCart[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
   let name = addCart[i].name;
   let price = addCart[i].value;
   const menuItem = {
     name: name,
     price: price,
   };
   window.localStorage.setItem('ProductsInCart_'+i, JSON.stringify(menuItem));
 });
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but indexing the local storage keys like that makes it impossible to iterate over the products. While this may "work", this is a _really_ inefficient and poorly maintainable approach.